# Sum all elements in each subarray of a 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum

I've got the following 2d array and I want to sum all of the elements in each subarray.

Input:

```
$main_array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 5],
    [8, 4, 3]
]
```

Desired Result:

```
[6, 11, 15]
```

I tried the following code:

```
foreach ($main_array as $key => $value)
    $main_array[$key] = Array('1' => array_sum($value));
print_r($main_array);
```

But the array structure I got was:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [1] => 6 
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [1] => 11
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [1] => 15 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're calling Array function you're explicitly making an array so you have to remove this from `Array('1'=>array_sum($value));`

This is how your code should look like

```
foreach ($main_array as $key => $value)
  $main_array[$key] = array_sum($value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  foreach ($main_array as $key => $value)
     $main_array[$key] = array_sum($value);
```

That is, place the sum directly in the top level array.

Answer (score 1):

Call `array_sum()` on every row in your input array.  `array_map()` makes this operation expressive, concise, and doesn't require any new variables to be declared.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OiNOu))

```
$array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 5],
    [8, 4, 3],
];

var_export(array_map('array_sum', $array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 6,
  1 => 11,
  2 => 15,
)
```