# Reduce each row of a 2d array to a single element containing the sum of the original row values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

How can I sum the subarray elements for each row of a 2d array.

```
[
    'Item 1' => [8, 5, 4],
    'Item 2' => [24, 4],
    'Item 3' => [23, 4],
]
```

Can each row be consolidated into a single element containing the sum of its original values?

```
[
    'Item 1' => [17],
    'Item 2' => [28],
    'Item 3' => [27],
]
```

I previously tried to use `array_merge_recursive()` to merge 2 arrays of the same keys together, but now I want to to add their elements together so they only have element `[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to achieve your goal:

```
$array = array('Item1' => array(1, 3), 'Item2' => array(3, 4));

$array = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_sum($item);
}, $array);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result would be:

```
array(2) {
  ["Item1"]=>
  int(4)
  ["Item2"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

If you really need the result to be an array with the sum of the items then change the return to:

```
return array(array_sum($item));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do long way like this

```
foreach($array as $key => $element){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($element as $value){
        $sum += $value;
    }
    $result[$key][0] = $sum;
}
```

Basically like this you will browse thru every element of array and you will create sum of desired elements

Answer (score 0):

If your question was how to reduce the row data of your 2d array to a flat, associative array, then Mihai's working snippet can be condensed further by simply nominating `array_sum()` as the callback using its string name. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L8pb0))

```
var_export(
    array_map('array_sum', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Item 1' => 17,
  'Item 2' => 28,
  'Item 3' => 27,
)
```

I have demonstrated this technique as an answer on a question from 2011: [Sum all elements in each subarray of a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68147634/2943403).

Using `array_map()` is safe because when passed a single input, the original first level keys are preserved.

---

To modify calculate the total for each subarray AND preserve the input array's 2d structure by reducing the rows to single-element arrays, you can use any of the 3 snippets below to generate this type of result:

```
[
  'Item 1' => [17],
  'Item 2' => [28],
  'Item 3' => [27],
]
```

1. You can make the callback function slightly more verbose. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZDGDc))

   ```
   var_export(
       array_map(fn($row) => [array_sum($row)], $array)
   );
   ```

2. You do not need to use `array_map()` though. You can use a `foreach()` loop and modify each row of the original array by reference and make iterated calls of `array_sum()`.  The similarity to earlier snippets is rather obvious. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NQMp8))

   ```
   foreach ($array as &$row) {
       $row = [array_sum($row)];
   }
   var_export($array);
   ```

3. If you have some unrealistic interview questions that asks you do to this task with no function calls, then you can implement nested function calls. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8ONFn))

   ```
   foreach ($array as &$row) {       // iterate the original rows
       foreach ($row as $i => $v) {  // iterate a copy of the row's data
           if (!$i) {                // if processing the [0] key
               $row = [$v];          // overwrite the original $row value with the first value as a single-element array
           } else {
               $row[0] += $v;        // add the new value to the first element's value
           }
       }
   }
   var_export($array);
   ```