# Sum loops several arrays

Tags: php, loops

I don't know how I can get the sum

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["Dato1"]=> string(6) "714084" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["Dato2"]=> string(6) "600397" 
    } 
}

 array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["Dato1"]=> string(6) "714084" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["Dato2"]=> string(6) "600397" 
    } 
}
```

The idea is:

sum: 25+125+95 = 245

sum: 32+52+57 = 141

```
<?php
$sum=0;

$suma =0;
$iterator = new MultipleIterator;
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($datoscaser));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($datosmapfre));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($datosbbva));

foreach ($iterator as $values) {

}

            ?>
```

I have tried to do this:

```
foreach ($iterator as $values) {
$suma=$sum+$values;
}
```

but it tells me that it is an array

Comment: Start with `var_dump($values)`. It's an array like `[25, 125, 95]`, right? How do you sum an array of values? [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum). Now just add that to `$sum`…

Comment: See fixed demo https://onecompiler.com/php/3ykkgr7x9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing of all elements in the sub array - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782448/summing-of-all-elements-in-the-sub-array-php)

Comment: This is the var_dump($values)  array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Dato1"]=> string(6) "714084" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Dato2"]=> string(6) "372741" } [2]=> array(1) { ["Dato3"]=> string(6) "195867" } } array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Dato1"]=> string(6) "600397" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Dato2"]=> string(6) "-37872" } [2]=> array(1) { ["Dato3"]=> string(5) "97276" } }

Comment: foreach ($iterator as $values) {
  $sum += array_sum($values);
}

echo $sum; The result $sum is "0"

Comment: @Rubius I think the array_sum suggestion was on the basis that the arrays were simple arrays, but they're not.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
$a = [
    ["Dato1"=> "714084"],
    ["Dato2"=> "600397"]
];

function sum($carry, $item)
{
    return $carry += array_values($item)[0];
}

var_dump(array_reduce($a, "sum"));
```

if you want something more flexible :

```
<?php

$a = [
    ["Dato1"=> "714084"],
    ["Dato2"=> "600397"],
    14
];


$total = 0;

//Does not persist
array_walk_recursive( $a, function($value, $key) use (&$total) {
    return $total += (int)$value;
}, $total);

echo $total;
```

Comment: for $iterator tell me: Found 'MultipleIterator'

Comment: You don't need to use `MultipleIterator ` use PHP native function

Comment: But I don't understand how to insert that in what I need, because I have to go through the three arrays and add each of them separately